# How do you display entries in a specific (custom) order?

Tags: entries, entry-type

I want to display entries in a specific custom order in Craft. For example entry Id 1, then Id 5, then Id 3.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using a structure. You can reorder them in the CP.

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('your_structure') %}
  {{ entry.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option if you can't use structures is to have a global that is a collection of entries, and use that global to determine which entries and in what order.

```
{% for e in myGlobal.myEntries %}
  {{ e.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Structures aren't available in the free version of Craft, but a useful workaround is to simply manipulate the entry published date to accomplish a custom sort, as Craft orders entries from newest to oldest by default. It's a hack, but it's useful in a pinch.